# Error setting up WORHP license and parameters file

Tags: worhp

I am trying use WORHP toghether with AMPL on my Linux Mint (v19.3) machine, but I just can't figure out how to properly set up the license file (and probably the .xml file as well).

I've placed AMPL's and WORHP's binaries, as well as `libworhp.so`, `.lic` and `.xml` files, in the same directory as follows:

> ```
> user@laptop:/opt/AMPL$ ls -la
> total 121676
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root       4096 May 30 22:38 .
> drwxr-xr-x 9 root   root       4096 May 29 21:43 ..
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 500    users   1226960 May  2 17:47 ampl 
> -r--r--r-- 1 user   user        690 May 29 20:01 ampl.lic
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    4100512 May 29 22:00 libworhp.so
> -r--r--r-- 1 root   root        175 May 30 22:53 rosenbrock.mod
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root     339400 May 29 21:43 worhp_ampl
> -r--r--r-- 1 user   user       1122 May 30 21:56 worhp.lic
> -r--r--r-- 1 root   root      20239 May 29 22:34 worhp.xml
> ```

The binary file is called `worhp_ampl` and `rosenbrock.mod` is a valid AMPL example file.

Still, I get the following error message whenever I try to solve the model with:

> ```
> user@laptop:/opt/AMPL$ ampl rosenbrock.mod   
> ReadParamsNoInit: Used parameter file worhp.xml  
> * Read 268/268 parameters.  
> WORHP: Using data file /tmp/at9188.  Error (License): Could not open license file.  
> * Local MACs:
>     - 00:90:f5:93:e9:62
>     - 74:f0:6d:85:27:ee  
> WorhpInit: Could not obtain license.
>  Unsuccessful termination: License error.
>  Error (AMPL_Init): Error in WorhpInit.
> exit value 1
> <BREAK>
> ```

This error only happens if I set WORHP's corresponding parameter and license environment variables (because I need to use WORHP and AMPL outside of this installation directory).

> ```
> user@laptop:/opt/AMPL$ echo $WORHP_PARAM_FILE  
> :/opt/AMPL/worhp.xml
> ueser@laptop:/opt/AMPL$ echo $WORHP_LICENSE_FILE  
> :/opt/AMPL/worhp.lic
> ```

On the other hand, everything works (only inside the `/opt/AMPL` directory) if I remove the declaration of `WORHP_PARAM_FILE` and `WORHP_LICENSE_FILE` from my `.bashrc`.

I couldn't figure out how to do this just by reading WORHP's User's Guide, so I would like to kindly ask for a little help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by adding the following to my .bashrc file

```
WORHP_PARAM_FILE=/opt/AMPL/worhp.xml 
export WORHP_PARAM_FILE 
WORHP_LICENSE_FILE=/opt/AMPL/worhp.lic 
export WORHP_LICENSE_FILE
```

Instead of the previous:

```
export WORHP_PARAM_FILE=$WORHP_PARAM_FILE:/opt/AMPL/worhp.xml 
export WORHP_LICENSE_FILE=$WORHP_LICENSE_FILE:/opt/AMPL/worhp.lic
```